Can a cosigner on the car loan refuse to sign off the title once the loan is paid off?
I am the cobuyer of a car and make all of the payments as the vehicle is mine. A family member is listed as the primary buyer as they helped me obtain the loan due to bad credit at the time.
I plan on paying this loan off within the next few months. My family member and I are no longer on speaking terms. I fear that when I pay the note off, they won't want to give me 100% title rights to my name.
Do I have any legal options if they were to refuse to sign off the car slip to my name? The DMV currently has both of us register as the owners, with the word "or" and not "and".
Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Whether they are a cosigner or not doesn't seem to matter in this case; if their name is on the title as one of the owners, and law in your area requires that everyone on the title sign... You chose to put them on the title, you get to deal with the consequences thereof. If you need to know what's possible without their cooperation, you need a lawyer.

From a layman's point of view, the "or" is in your favor.

Did your co-buyer contribute any money to the purchase of the car? If so, I would argue they do have some claim on ownership. If not, you have a couple of good answers already.

See also Car dealership put my name as the buyer without consent, when I was just the co-signer on the loan.  That question is from the other perspective, but the information is likely still relevant.

"When you cosign a loan, you agree to be responsible for someone else's debt."--according to the FTC. Since the cosigner is taking on some of the risk, he might argue that he is entitled to something in return..

The title and the body contradict each other - are they "cosigner" or "primary buyer"?

If it was me, and you have good credit now, I would take care of this today.  As a preliminary step you can wait in line at the DMV and make sure the "or" allows you to reissue the title in your name only.  If they say "yes", no problem, then get this done.
Apply for a used car loan from your bank or credit union.  Even if you have to pay a bit more interest on this loan, refi the car and have the title in your name only.  Given that you are likely to have the loan for a "short" time, the extra interest paid won't matter in respect to the equity in the car.


The DMV currently has both of us register as the owners, with the word
"or" and not "and".

This phrase is important. "Or" means that only one of you has to sign the forms to sell the car. That will make it easier for you to sell the car, but it also means that they can sell the car.
If the phrase was "And" and they refused to sell, one option you might have is to sue them in your local small claims court. In the United States these are courts that have low costs, no lawyers, but they limit you to the maximum amount you can sue somebody for.

they helped me obtain the loan due to bad credit at the time.

While the loan exists there are three owners. The lender and (Gabriel  or X). When the loan has been paid off, the lender should be removed from the title. At that point the law sees you and your relative as equals with the 100% right to sell to a new owner.
You should get local advice. An organization you belong to may provide free or inexpensive legal advice. Some banks do, some credit unions, some employers.
You should determine a course of action before making the final loan payment.  You could even offer them a gift to allow the car to be transferred to you.
Always get agreements in writing before signing co-loan agreements. They need to specify what happens during and after the loan. It specifies who makes the payments and repairs, and what happens when the loan has been paid off.
These types of agreements show the plan to much more detail than relying on the difference between "And" and "Or".

A lender is not an owner. They are a lienholder, and they go in a separate section of the title. They limited rights: e.g. they can only take possession of the car if you don't pay as agreed, and their rights can be involuntarily terminated simply by paying the entire amount owed.

The part of this question that makes me nervous is: "[the] family member is listed as the primary buyer" which means probably that is the person the released title will be mailed to, unless the OP gets this cleaned up beforehand.

So... couldn't any one of the owners just sell the car to themselves for 1 symbolic dollar without the consent of the other owner and thus get them off the title at any time?

I agree about local advice, and the best free advice will come from the government agency that does the title transfer and issues a new title.

@Philipp, because there is a loan on the car the bank/credit union probably has possession of the title, for exactly this reason: they don't want the owners to be able to sell it out from under them.

@Philipp In my jurisdiction, any time a vehicle is sold, the new owner must pay sales tax to the government.  I may be wrong, but I think the tax is calculated based on the book value of the vehicle (how much that type of car would reasonably be expected to sell for), regardless of the actual purchase price.  So selling it to yourself for $1 could still end up costing you quite a bit in taxes (though it might still be worth it in a situation like this).

@GentlePurpleRain It's highly state dependent. Exemption rules on sales tax for title transfers varies significantly by state, but because OP says the co-signer is a family member, transfers between family members are usually tax-exempt (for some definition of family member). Further, many states simply do not have sales tax on cars: they see it as double taxation since they're property taxed.

@Philipp Cars (and boats, planes, and often mobile homes) are special cases, since there is a specific title transfer procedure through the state DMV. Generally, all of the owners have to sign the title certificate (often requiring notarization) and submit it to effect a change in ownership. In other cases, one could sign a contract and that's it, but for cars, the actual change in ownership requires involvement of the state DMV. Real estate is also another special case involving the county recorder. (In my state, your spouse may have to sign even if they're not on the deed.)

A car is owned by whoever the title says owns it. So it is not just your car, you share ownership with your relative. The fact that you paid for it doesn't change that.
You probably entered a contract with your relative that if you pay for everything, you have exclusive use of the car and they'll sign over their share once the loan is paid off. However, if you don't have this in writing and if your relative claims that you've agreed something different, it will be very hard to prove the existence of this contract.

The "Or" means only one person needs to sign the title in order to sell the car. Once the car is paid off, you will receive a clear title from the DMV. It does not matter who is listed first on the title. The "Or" is all that matters.
Make sure the DMV already has your address for registration and not the address of the co-owner.
You will not need his signature if/when you decide to sell the car. I've sold a car all by myself on plenty of occasions with just one signature with two "Or" owners on the title. It's no big deal. (I'm in California, FWIW).
You can also do a title transfer on an "Or" title with just one signature. So you can wait to receive the lien-free title with both names after the loan is paid off, then pay a small fee to the DMV to do a title transfer to just yourself. (I'm speaking about California -- but I would expect other states to be similar with "Or" titles -- check your DMV web site about title transfers.)
The other comments here asking you to get legal advice first seems like overkill. You've made the payments. You paid for it. You've used the car exclusively. When you have the title in hand, you can sell/transfer it without the other guy even knowing about it. Just do it.
Sure, your family member could try to get all legal about it if/when he ever finds out: "I was a co-owner, I should get half the money!" -- but it's a poor argument because he never paid for any part of it. It would cost him more than it's worth to litigate and he would likely lose.

If the title said "And" -- it's an entirely different kind of flying, altogether. Then you'd be stuck.

I don't see OP saying they want to sell the car, am I missing something?

Good point. I will edit answer.

Though make sure that the lien holder sends the title to you and not your relative, or else they could just re-title it to themselves just as easily as you're wanting to do for yourself in which case there really is no pain-free recourse for you.  Whoever has physical possession of the title (in this scenario with "OR" owners) is the one in control of the situation.

@Milwrdfan: That's a dangerous take.  Clearly if the relative has physical possession of the title, OP is not in control.  But if OP has the physical title, they are still not in control, the relative still might make use of his rights.
